# Connecting to oracle via JAX-RS

Tags: jax-rs

I'm developing a project to connect multiple android clients connect simultaneously via REST services.
So,how can I make the server side component connect to my oracle database using REST?
I mean can my class directly communicate with the DB or do i need to route the request via a servlet or something else?
I'm new to REST,so don't know much about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your architecture correctly, the flow is

Android client --> REST service --> DB

REST has nothing to do with DB access. You can use JDBC or popular ORM framework such as hibernate/toplink to communicate with your database. REST is a web service design model, which in your case, provides service to your android client.